# Instancing Nested Object (Dart)

Tags: dart

On trying to assign values to Nested Object Properties,`Dart treats the Nested Object(class OperandRange) as null`.
Default values have been assigned to the Nested Object Properties but the issue exists.

In the case below Nested Object Class `OperandRange` should be assigned minimum and maximum values but dart considers it to the `Null`.

How to resolve this?

***Code***

```
import 'dart:io';

//Nested Object Class
class OperandRange{
  double _minValue = 0;
  double _maxValue = 10;

  OperandRange(this._minValue  , this._maxValue);

  double  get minValue => _minValue;

  double get maxValue => _maxValue;

 
  set minValue(double _val){

    _minValue = (_val)  ;
  }

 
  set maxValue(double _val){

    _maxValue = (_val)  ;
  }

}


class OperationData{

  List<OperandRange> operandList = [];//Nested Object
  List<String> operatorList = [] ;

  OperationData({this.operandList, this.operatorList});
}

void main(){
  int _operationCount = 2;
  OperationData _operation = OperationData();
  for(int _index = 0 ; _index < _operationCount ; _index++) {
    stdout.write(" Operation $_index - Name(string): ");
    _operation.operatorList[_index] = stdin.readLineSync();

    //Null Object
    stdout.write(" Operand $_index - Minimum Value (double) : ");
    _operation.operandList[_index]._minValue =
        double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());
    stdout.write(" Operand $_index - Maximum Value (double): ");
    _operation.operandList[_index]._maxValue =
        double.parse(stdin.readLineSync());

  }
}
```

***Error***

```
Operation 0 - Name(string): Add
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]=' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []=(0, "Add")
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      main (1.dart:41:28)
#2      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:283:19)
#3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)

Process finished with exit code 255
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what's happening.

You initialize `operandList` with a nested list. But this never has any effect because you also initialize it in `OperationData` constructor. Once you mention it in constructor arguments, it will either be set to a value you pass to constructor, or set to null if you do not pass this argument to constructor.

For your purpose you may remove constructor altogether as you never pass anything to it. Then your `[]` defaults will stand.

Otherwise, if in some cases you need to initialize it with a custom list, you may do it like this:

```dart
class OperationData{
  List<OperandRange> operandList;
  List<String> operatorList;

  OperationData({
    List<OperandRange> operandList,
    List<String>operatorList,
  }) :
    this.operandList = operandList ?? <OperandList>[],
    this.operatorList = operatorList ?? <String>[]
  ;
}
```

The same goes for your `OperandRange` class. `0` and `10` defaults will never be used as the constructor requires explicit values. By the way, I do not see `OperandRange` creation at all. The list stays empty. You will catch a next error when trying to access an index out of bounds when you fix the first error.

Also you should upgrade to Dart 2.12 if possible. It introduced null-safety that would show you this error at compile time.

Comment: OperandRange class is the nested class which gets called when an instance of its parent is created and dart is treating it as  Null .The default properties were  set so that Dart would   recognize the nested OperandRange  class and create an instance of it along with its parent..... Also ,constructors can't be initialized to Dynamic types(like dynamic list above ),the constructor assignment must be a constant.

Comment: There are no nested classes in Dart. Dart would not create its instance. Also, constructors can be initialzed with dynamic types. As for non-constant default values, they were not mentioned.

Comment: Nested classes exist in Java. These classes can only be used inside the class they are defined in. You might have meant nested objects which exist in C++ and created automatically with an object that contains them. But these do not exist in Dart either. Here you have a list of instances. This list is empty at best and null at worst. If it was not so, how would Dart know how many elements to create in `operandList`?

Comment: I see. I have edited the answer. There was a confusion in terms.